# Stringify only one object in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm working with fabricJS. It's an awesome library for drawing.

```
var data = JSON.stringify(canvas);
```

Above command is used to get all the objects along with their properties in `JSON` format. However, I want to stringfy only an object.

For eg. Creating a rectangle using fabric

```
var rec = new fabric.Rect({
    left: mouse_pos.x,
    top: mouse_pos.y,
    width: 75,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'white',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 3,
    padding: 10
  });
canvas.add(rec);
```

I want to get the `JSON` of only this object(rectangle) being added to the canvas and not the `JSON` of whole of the canvas being rendered.
May be something like `var data = JSON.stringfy(rec);`. Is there any way to do so because I want to send the latest object being added to the canvas over sockets and not the whole canvas object which will in turn consumes unnecessary bandwidth because of the JSON object size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can! :)

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: mouse_pos.x,
    top: mouse_pos.y,
    width: 75,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'white',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 3,
    padding: 10
  });

canvas.add(rect);

// get last item
var obj = canvas.item(canvas.size() - 1);

// stringify only one object
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: Perfection! Thanks a lot @Keinz.  Just one thing I would like to share: in order to load this object in future `canvas.loadFromJSON(obj)`,one has to do `obj = '{"objects":['+ obj +']}';` after getting `obj` otherwise fabric will report `length Exception`.

Comment: Maybe this post helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19364574/2323945
`canvas.loadFromJSON` needs objects property.

Comment: Hey @Kienz, please can you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692334/loadfromdatalessjson-not-providing-the-desired-output-in-fabric-js

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just turn your options object into JSON? Then you could send it through sockets, get the JSON on your receiver, parse it and apply into the `fabric.Rect` function to draw your rect there.

```
var options = {
    left: mouse_pos.x,
    top: mouse_pos.y,
    width: 75,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'white',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 3,
    padding: 10
};

var rec = new fabric.Rect(options);
canvas.add(rec);

var yourData = JSON.stringify(options); // turns your options object into JSON

// ...rest of your code, that sends it through sockets...
```

Comment: What in case of `isDrawingMode=true`? The path is automatically rendered to the canvas without even explicitly adding it to the canvas? So, how will I set the options and stringify them ?

Comment: Also going by this will overhead the cost of manually updating each option upon any transformation? Isn;t there any predefined thing in fabric to take care of this?

Comment: Hmm, I do not know Fabric.js very well. I don't really know what I'd do in this case.