# Concat two JSON object for adding data in fabic.js canvas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, fabricjs

```
{
  "objects": [{
    "type": "i-text",
    "originX": "left",
    "originY": "top",
    "left": 253.75,
    "top": 377.4,
    "width": 293.49609375,
    "height": 45.199999999999996,
    "fill": "#454545",
    "stroke": null,
    "strokeWidth": 1,
    "strokeDashArray": null,
    "strokeLineCap": "butt",
    "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
    "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
    "scaleX": 1,
    "scaleY": 1,
    "angle": 0,
    "flipX": false,
    "flipY": false,
    "opacity": 1,
    "shadow": null,
    "visible": true,
    "clipTo": null,
    "backgroundColor": "",
    "fillRule": "nonzero",
    "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
    "transformMatrix": null,
    "skewX": 0,
    "skewY": 0,
    "text": "Start typing here",
    "fontSize": 40,
    "fontWeight": "normal",
    "fontFamily": "arial",
    "fontStyle": "",
    "lineHeight": 1.16,
    "textDecoration": "",
    "textAlign": "left",
    "textBackgroundColor": "",
    "charSpacing": 0,
    "originalScaleX": 1,
    "originalScaleY": 1,
    "originalLeft": 253.751953125,
    "originalTop": 377.4,
    "lockMovementX": false,
    "lockMovementY": false,
    "lockScalingX": false,
    "lockScalingY": false,
    "lockUniScaling": false,
    "lockRotation": false,
    "id": 8454,
    "styles": {}
  }],
  "background": "#ffffff",
  "height": 800,
  "width": 801,
  "originalHeight": 800,
  "originalWidth": 801
}

{
  "objects": [{
    "type": "i-text",
    "originX": "left",
    "originY": "top",
    "left": 253.75,
    "top": 377.4,
    "width": 293.49609375,
    "height": 45.199999999999996,
    "fill": "#454545",
    "stroke": null,
    "strokeWidth": 1,
    "strokeDashArray": null,
    "strokeLineCap": "butt",
    "strokeLineJoin": "miter",
    "strokeMiterLimit": 10,
    "scaleX": 1,
    "scaleY": 1,
    "angle": 0,
    "flipX": false,
    "flipY": false,
    "opacity": 1,
    "shadow": null,
    "visible": true,
    "clipTo": null,
    "backgroundColor": "",
    "fillRule": "nonzero",
    "globalCompositeOperation": "source-over",
    "transformMatrix": null,
    "skewX": 0,
    "skewY": 0,
    "text": "Start typing here",
    "fontSize": 40,
    "fontWeight": "normal",
    "fontFamily": "arial",
    "fontStyle": "",
    "lineHeight": 1.16,
    "textDecoration": "",
    "textAlign": "left",
    "textBackgroundColor": "",
    "charSpacing": 0,
    "originalScaleX": 1,
    "originalScaleY": 1,
    "originalLeft": 253.751953125,
    "originalTop": 377.4,
    "lockMovementX": false,
    "lockMovementY": false,
    "lockScalingX": false,
    "lockScalingY": false,
    "lockUniScaling": false,
    "lockRotation": false,
    "id": 6668,
    "styles": {}
  }],
  "background": "#ffffff",
  "height": 800,
  "width": 801,
  "originalHeight": 800,
  "originalWidth": 801
}
```

i have this 2 fabric.js json object which i want to concat and load to canvas by using fabric loadJSON method??

Comment: Please share effort? I'm not closing as dupe as i'm not sure about fabric, but you can refer [how to merge objects in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically) for merging

Comment: I don't believe that's what Sagar Adke is looking for, but only he can speak to it.  I have given him what I believe is what he's looking for below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options depending on what **Sagar Adke** is ultimately trying to achieve.  However, I think these might be closer to what he's looking for:

[image]

**OPTION 1:**

Load the canvas with json1 stringify'ing first, clone the object since loading again will clear the canvas, load the canvas with json2 stringify'ing first, and then add the cloned object.

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(JSON.stringify(json1), canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
var item = canvas.item(0).clone();
canvas.loadFromJSON(JSON.stringify(json2), canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
// only needed since objects are identical and I wanted to show both objects
item.set({
  top: item.top - 70
});
canvas.add(item);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Working JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/wxjnu7pd/.

**OPTION 2:**

Push json2 object onto json1 object stack, and then load the canvas with json1 stringify'ing first.

```
json1.objects.push(json2.objects[0]);
// the next line will put both objects on top of each other, since they're identical
canvas.loadFromJSON(JSON.stringify(json1), canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
canvas.renderAll();
```

Working JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/okb2uj1m/.

**OPTION 3:**

No need to stringify json first with this option, just pass an array of fabric objects to enlivenObjects (in fabric.util), and then add each object to the canvas in its callback.

```
fabric.util.enlivenObjects([json1.objects[0], json2.objects[0]], function(objects) {
  var origRenderOnAddRemove = canvas.renderOnAddRemove;
  canvas.renderOnAddRemove = false;
  objects.forEach(function(o, i) {
    // IF only needed since objects are identical and I wanted to show both objects
    if (i == 0) o.set({
      top: o.top - 70
    });
    canvas.add(o);
  });
  canvas.renderOnAddRemove = origRenderOnAddRemove;
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Working JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/jnkLjrn4/.

(Option 3 credit goes to a FabricJS master, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364574/3389046)

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of object manipulation, I always have underscore.js ready. It's the first js library I import when starting a new project.

http://underscorejs.org

Take a look at: _.extend (better even, take a look at the whole lib ;))

```
_.extend({name: 'moe'}, {age: 50});
=> {name: 'moe', age: 50}
```